# Same QUERY, different behaviour

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Fellows,

I have a Google spreadsheet at
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XUQcBld7kJ1r_Eo0njBYdA4Ox6hDow0Uwe419EXkEf4/edit?usp=sharing
that I used a same estructured QUERY to search/sumarize values in other pages. But one of the pages seems not working despite the same QUERY. In the image above

[image]

you can see two groups os cells, orange and green, both isn't showing any values. Ih the green ones the QUERY is

```
=INDEX(QUERY(gD_YTB!A2:I*1; "SELECT sum(Col6) WHERE Col1 > "&DATE.VALUE(TODAY()-8)))
```

In this cells, if I change "-8" to "-20" I can access the values and eveything runs fine. But in the orange cells it didn't worked and the QUERY is basically the same

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FB_Posts!A2:U*1; "SELECT sum(Col18) WHERE Col1 > "&DATE.VALUE(TODAY()-8)))
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates need to be handled specifically in query. Try this in cell `Sumario7!B9`:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({FB_Posts!A2:U}; "SELECT sum(Col18) WHERE Col1 > date '"&text(TODAY()-8;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ";0))
```

`{}` is instead of `*1`.

Comment: It worked! Do you mind to explain why to use "yyyy-mm-dd" and why you use the "0" almost at the end of the query?

Comment: Sure. "yyyy-mm-dd" is just the way dates need to be passed in query. I don't think there is any way around it. "0" is the header part of query. 0 indicates data, 1 indicates a column header. SInce your range is A2:U, it needs 0. A1:U would need 1. See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB